# What are advantages of Artificial Neural Networks over Support Vector Machines?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, svm

ANN (Artificial Neural Networks) and SVM (Support Vector Machines) are two popular strategies for supervised machine learning and classification. It's not often clear which method is better for a particular project, and I'm certain the answer is always "it depends." Often, a combination of both along with Bayesian classification is used.

These questions on Stackoverflow have already been asked regarding ANN vs SVM:

[ANN and SVM classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326485/ann-and-svm-classification)

[what the difference among ANN, SVM and KNN in my classification question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316671/what-the-difference-among-ann-svm-and-knn-in-my-classification-question)

[Support Vector Machine or Artificial Neural Network for text processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434536/support-vector-machine-or-artificial-neural-network-for-text-processing)

In this question, I'd like to know *specifically* what aspects of an ANN (specifically, a Multilayer Perceptron) might make it desirable to use over an SVM? The reason I ask is because it's easy to answer the *opposite* question: Support Vector Machines are often superior to ANNs because they avoid two major weaknesses of ANNs:

(1) ANNs often converge on *local minima* rather than global minima, meaning that they are essentially "missing the big picture" sometimes (or missing the forest for the trees)

(2) ANNs often *overfit* if training goes on too long, meaning that for any given pattern, an ANN might start to consider the noise as part of the pattern.

SVMs don't suffer from either of these two problems. However, it's not readily apparent that SVMs are meant to be a total replacement for ANNs. So what *specific* advantage(s) does an ANN have over an SVM that might make it applicable for certain situations? I've listed *specific* advantages of an SVM over an ANN, now I'd like to see a list of ANN advantages (if any).

Comment: I imagine most of the answers to this question will be speculative or based on evidence, because there are very few theoretical guarantees on the power of these machines. For instance (if I recall correctly), it is unknown whether an n-layer feed-forward neural network is more powerful than a 2-layer network. So how can we say that one is better than the other in principle if we don't even understand the relationships between slight variations of the same model?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Judging from the examples you provide, I'm assuming that by ANNs, you mean multilayer feed-forward networks (FF nets for short), such as multilayer perceptrons, because those are in direct competition with SVMs.

One specific benefit that these models have over SVMs is that their size is fixed: they are *parametric* models, while SVMs are non-parametric. That is, in an ANN you have a bunch of hidden layers with sizes *h*<sub>1</sub> through *h*<sub>*n*</sub> depending on the number of features, plus bias parameters, and those make up your model. By contrast, an SVM (at least a kernelized one) consists of a set of support vectors, selected from the training set, with a weight for each. In the worst case, the number of support vectors is exactly the number of training samples (though that mainly occurs with small training sets or in degenerate cases) and in general its model size scales linearly. In natural language processing, SVM classifiers with tens of thousands of support vectors, each having hundreds of thousands of features, is not unheard of.

Also, [online training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) of FF nets is very simple compared to online SVM fitting, and predicting can be quite a bit faster.

**EDIT**: all of the above pertains to the general case of kernelized SVMs. Linear SVM are a special case in that they *are* parametric and allow online learning with simple algorithms such as stochastic gradient descent.

Comment: Another reason can be found in this paper: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/bengio-lecun-07.pdf. In short, the author states that "deep architectures" can represent "intelligent" behaviour/functions etc. more efficiently than "shallow architectures" like SVMs.

Comment: As an aside, deep learning loses the "advantages" given here for MLPs (fixed size, simpler training) somewhat. I am not sure that these advantages are worth it, though.

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri: deep learning is a pretty broad set of techniques, but the ones that I'm familiar with retain the benefit of the models being parametric (fixed-size).

Comment: Two comments: the online training point is true, but there is a variant of SVM-like classifiers specifically designed for online learning, called MIRA (a type of passive-aggressive classifier) for which updates are trivial. Secondly, it's worth pointing out that many neural nets can be formulated as SVMs through the kernel trick.

Comment: @BenAllison: linear SVMs can be trained online trivially, that's true (SGD + hinge loss is even easier than MIRA). But for online training of kernel SVMs, you need specialized algorithms. I was assuming that's what the OP means, since the difference between linear SVMs and multilayer nets is even easier to tell: multilayer nets are universal approximators, while linear SVMs are just that: linear models.

Comment: @FredFoo also ANN can be stuck in local minima where as support vector machines isn't prone this problem.

Answer (score 66):

One obvious advantage of artificial neural networks over support vector machines is that artificial neural networks may have any number of outputs, while support vector machines have only one. The most direct way to create an n-ary classifier with support vector machines is to create n support vector machines and train each of them one by one. On the other hand, an n-ary classifier with neural networks can be trained in one go. Additionally, the neural network will make more sense because it is one whole, whereas the support vector machines are isolated systems. This is especially useful if the outputs are inter-related.

For example, if the goal was to classify hand-written digits, ten support vector machines would do. Each support vector machine would recognize exactly one digit, and fail to recognize all others. Since each handwritten digit cannot be meant to hold more information than just its class, it makes no sense to try to solve this with an artificial neural network.

However, suppose the goal was to model a person's hormone balance (for several hormones) as a function of easily measured physiological factors such as time since last meal, heart rate, etc ... Since these factors are all inter-related, artificial neural network regression makes more sense than support vector machine regression.

Comment: Actually, there exist true multiclass formulations of the support vector machine (see Crammer & Singer's papers). I believe LibSVM contains an implementation of these.

Comment: However, train a multiclass SVM is not so easy and the performance seems to be better in the OVA than AVA approach.

Comment: " it makes no sense to try to solve this with an artificial neural network" You can use a neural network to solve classification of handwritten digits. I have done this as an hw assignment for a class. The output layer contains probabilities of all the digits. The class with the highest probability is  used as the hypothesis. I had a 94% accuracy rate.

Comment: You mean create n number of 1 vs N-1 SVM classifiers vs using NN to make n outputs.  SVM seem to be slower in this way?

Answer (score 50):

One thing to note is that the two are actually very related.  Linear SVMs are equivalent to single-layer NN's (i.e., perceptrons), and multi-layer NNs can be expressed in terms of SVMs.  See [here](http://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2004_links_icml.pdf) for some details.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use a kernel SVM you have to guess the kernel. However, ANNs are universal approximators with only guessing to be done is the width (approximation accuracy) and height (approximation efficiency). If you design the optimization problem correctly you do not over-fit (please see bibliography for over-fitting). It also depends on the training examples if they scan correctly and uniformly the search space. Width and depth discovery is the subject of integer programming.

Suppose you have bounded functions f(.) and bounded universal approximators on I=[0,1] with range again I=[0,1] for example that are parametrized by a real sequence of compact support U(.,a) with the property that there exists a sequence of sequences with

```
lim sup { |f(x) - U(x,a(k) ) | : x } =0
```

and you draw examples and tests `(x,y)` with a distribution D on `IxI`.

For a prescribed support, what you do is to find the best a such that

```
sum {  ( y(l) - U(x(l),a) )^{2} | : 1<=l<=N } is minimal
```

Let this `a=aa` which is a random variable!, the over-fitting is then

average using `D and D^{N} of ( y - U(x,aa) )^{2}`

Let me explain why, if you select `aa` such that the error is minimized, then for a rare set of values you have perfect fit. However, since they are rare the average is never 0. You want to minimize the second although you have a discrete approximation to D. And keep in mind that the support length is free.

Answer (score 16):

One answer I'm missing here:
Multi-layer perceptron is able to find relation between features. For example it is necessary in computer vision when a raw image is provided to the learning algorithm and now Sophisticated features are calculated.
Essentially the intermediate levels can calculate new unknown features.

Answer (score 13):

We should also consider that the SVM system can be applied *directly* to non-metric spaces, such as the set of labeled graphs or strings. In fact, the internal kernel function can be generalized properly to virtually any kind of input, provided that the positive definiteness requirement of the kernel is satisfied. On the other hand, to be able to use an ANN on a set of labeled graphs, explicit embedding procedures must be considered.

Comment: In my mind, constructing a sensible kernel and constructing a sensible metric embedding are equally problematic. So this is just a comment that there may be more varied kernels than metrics, but I don't really buy that. http://www.ohli.de/download/papers/Deza2009.pdf