# Which type of neural network is good for text classification(extractive summary)

Tags: nlp, neural-network, summarization

Currently i am working on text summarization.I am planning to use neural network to generate extractive summary of given text. Which type of neural network is good for text classification.

Answer (score 0):

[Feed-forward neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network) are a common type of neural network used for modelling in text summarization tasks (sometimes called **feed-forward neural network language models** (NNLMs)), often following in the line of [Bengio et al. (2003)](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=944966). Saying that, there is a huge amount of variation in the finer details --- compare two recent attempts:

- [Denil et al.'s (2014)](http://mdenil.com/projects/#deep-nlp) usage of [convolutional neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) --- see also [the code used for the research on GitHub](https://github.com/mdenil/txtnets).
- [Rush et al.'s (2015)](http://aclweb.org/anthology/D/D15/D15-1044.pdf) NAMAS (Neural Attention Model for Abstractive Sentence Summarization) --- see also [the code used for the research on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/NAMAS).

There is no single "best" neural network used for text summarization (otherwise, there wouldn't be so many different approaches). [The Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) has [an excellent answer introducing some issues in defining a feed-forward neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1097) as well [as an answer contrasting feed-forward networks with the main alternative type of neural network, recurrent neural networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2218). Additionally, SO has [a very good answer contrasting neural networks with their main competitor in many tasks, support vector machines.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11633343/1391325)

Comment: @Narendra: If this answer helped you out, I'd be very grateful if you could [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as I'm currently trawling for a few extra reputation points; Thanks a lot for the help.