# différence between SVM and neural network

Tags: neural-network

I do not understand what are the différence between neural network and SVM.
In both cases there are learning/training mecanism...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632516/what-are-advantages-of-artificial-neural-networks-over-support-vector-machines), which includes a good discussion of the topic and links to others.