# Python multiclass classification

Tags: python, svm, multiclass-classification

I have a working example of a multiclass classifier (using sklearn.svm) on text data. At one pass, I can only train/test one feature. Is it possible to stack several features in one classifier? For concreteness, my data has the following characteristics:

`feature 1: 1c1, 1c2, 1c3, 1c4
feature 2: 2c1,2c2
feature 3: 3c1,3c2,3c3,3c4,3c5
feature 4: 4c1,4c2,4c3`

Currently, I can run a training pass for feature 1 and repeat for feature 2 etc.
How can I stack them together to get an output vector like `[1c4,2c1,3c5,4c2]`? This is not a multi-label problem because feature sets {1..n} are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Kind of difficult to answer without seeing the architecture or any reasoning behind _why_ you can only train/test one feature at a time. I see no reason for this limitation?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Every newspaper story,coming to us from around the world,  has the following features: 1. Story_type 2. Brand_mention 3. client_focus 4. tonality and 5. segment. To give you a quick sense, class story_type can be (1c1) product review (1c2) interview of country marketing head (1c3) interview of country ceo (1c4) demand and sales figures and (1c5) accident reports featuring Toyota cars. so on. For tonality, the classes will be (4c1) positive, (4c2) neutral, (4c3) negative, and (4c4) negative, with escalation.

Comment: @OptimusCrime This is not a multi label problem, it is a five-track (output)  multiclass problem. How do I stack the SVM classifiers as in NN architectures to give an output vector `[1,2,2,1,5]` @mlguy

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no way to do this, per [Alan Sz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632516/what-are-advantages-of-artificial-neural-networks-over-support-vector-machines?rq=1)

> One obvious advantage of artificial neural networks over support vector machines is that artificial neural networks may have any number of outputs, while support vector machines have only one. The most direct way to create an n-ary classifier with support vector machines is to create n support vector machines and train each of them one by one. On the other hand, an n-ary classifier with neural networks can be trained in one go.